# Error: unqualified ID

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write binary data to a filestream `out` which I've opened as `std::ios::binary`. I'm trying to write to it using `ostream::write`.

```
int S = 0;
int space = htobe32(-120);

for (int g = 0; g < Z; ++g) 
        {
            for (int h = 0; h < Y; ++h) 
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < X; ++i)
                {
                    if (data_array[g][h][i] != 0)
                    {
                        S=htobe32(data_array[g][h][i]);
                        out.write(&S, std::sizeof(S));
                    }
                    else
                    {                
                        out.write(&space, std::sizeof(space));
                    }
                }                  
            }
         }
```

At the moment I'm getting `error: expected unqualified-id before ‘sizeof’` in both places I'm trying to write out.

Comment: It is plain `sizeof`, no `std::`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof()` is a language operator, not a part of the standard library, so you can't prefix it with `std`:

```
 sizeof(anything)
```